# What is the maximum polycount unity can handle

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-model

What is the maximum polycount unity can handle, I am building a furniture-based application in unity, my client wants high detailed 3D models. What is the maximum unity can handle, are there any best practices to keep the quality of assets and not affect the performance of the application. I am building the application for the following platforms, OSX, Windows, Android and iOS.

Comment: Wrong question. The question is what can your target device(s) handle? (I only know the limits for the HoloLens 1 e.g. which was kind of max 300.000 verts if you really want 60 FPS) As with every GameEngine ever made the best practise is to keep the quality of models as low as any possible. It also depends on materials/shaders and ofcourse your gamelogic (and physics)

Comment: This question is a little broad as @derHugo has noted, and some form of it (i.e. more specific to target device capabilities) would be better suited to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ since it's not about programming specifically.

Comment: Thank you guys, valuable inputs those. Will focus on the target devices. Maybe I need to communicate to the client about the target devices than talking about code specifics.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a hard techincal limit, other than 65k verticies per single mesh (if using default, 16bit indexing), but I don't think there's a limit on mesh count, and if you are reusing meshes, you can draw them using Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced, or if you fancy some buffer work, Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect.

With relatively modern graphics card, enough ram etc, you can easily work in the million range. You can push if further (tens of millions? hundreds of millions?) but at some point, ineviteably performance will go down.

So basically the answer is : any number that will fit in your RAM, with a secondary constraint dependeind on your hardware if you want it realtime (unity will render any amount of polygons if it doesn't run out of memory, but ludicrous amount of poly might take multiple seconds to render)

Comment: Essentially, materials have a bigger impact on render speed than meshes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want detailed objects and high performance, you can use level of detail, you can find more information here: [https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html#:~:text=and%20OpenGL%20Core-,Level%20of%20Detail%20(LOD),on%20it%20is%20greatly%20reduced.&text=An%20optimisation%20technique%20called%20Level,its%20distance%20from%20camera%20increases](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html#:%7E:text=and%20OpenGL%20Core-,Level%20of%20Detail%20(LOD),on%20it%20is%20greatly%20reduced.&text=An%20optimisation%20technique%20called%20Level,its%20distance%20from%20camera%20increases).

For Android devices, it's recommendable to maintain the poly count of the scene under 90k, in PC devices, this number can increase to 1 or 2 million.

But there are techniques like occlusion culling that increases the game performance.
See this link about it: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html